# codename one camera background

Tags: background, camera, streaming, codenameone

I'm creating app which needs a camera preview to be placed at the background. This is done in android easily by attaching a camera object to a preview (surface view). I need to do this using Codename One but the only APIs that is provided to access camera is through Capture class. The problem is that these functions require a user action.

Comment: FYI I edited the answer with recent information

Answer (score 0):

We now support placing a camera view finder right into your app with a new cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

Original answer for reference below:

At this point in time Codename One doesn't support camera overlays (augmented reality) functionality out of the box.

You might be able to do this by using the native interfaces functionality (explained in the developer guide), but obviously this isn't ideal.